# How to receive input from client in server?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, io, client-server

How do I send input on the client console to the server? So far I have

```
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            String input = br.readLine();
```

How do I get 'input' in the server side? What must I call on the clientSocket? I've tried this:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

out.write(input);
```

And on the server side:

```
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    while(true) {
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        String input = in.readLine();
        if (input.equals("2")) {
            System.out.println("activate receiveFile");
            receiveFile();
        }
```

However 'input' is certainly not '2' when I enter 2.

Comment: If it is not '2', then what is it? BTW, do you flush/close your output stream on the client?

Comment: Okay, so I did flush() on the output stream, and that worked, but the thing is I basically need to receive one stream at the same time: the first input gives the command (e.g. upload), and the second gives the filename to upload. But after I flush i can't access the filename again

Answer (score 0):

Try using PrintWriter(Writer out, boolean autoFlush) constructer when creating PrintWriter object. Eg: out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

Answer (score 0):

server side contructor

```
 try {
  is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(soc.getInputStream())));
  os = new PrintWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(soc.getOutputStream()), false);
  printWriterQueue = new PrintWriterQueue(this, os, is, timeout);
  soc.setSoTimeout(5000);
  start();
} catch (Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

you should use a thread so in the run

```
 while (!end) {
    do {
      try {
        st=is.readLine();
      } catch (InterruptedIOException ie) {
        st="";
      }
    } while (!end && st.length()==0);
```

client side contructor

```
soc     = new Socket(IpAddress, 2999);
    in      = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(soc.getInputStream()));
    out     = new PrintWriter(soc.getOutputStream());
    addText("Connection up and running...");
    soc.setSoTimeout(5000);
    printWriterQueue = new PrintWriterQueue(this, out, in, 10000);
    Thread th=new Thread(this);
    th.start();
```

a thread for the client too so in the run()

```
try {
  do {
    do {
      try {
        msg=in.readLine();
      } catch (InterruptedIOException ie) {
        msg="";
      }
    } while (!end && msg.length()==0);
    if (!end) {
      System.out.println("["+msg+"]");
    }
  } while (!end);
} catch (Exception exc) {
  exc.printStackTrace();
}
```